# Vue CLI 3 SPA in Subfolder, Static HTML Pages in Root

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli-3

**Using Vue CLI 3 how can I create a project that contains some static html files at the root of the public directory and an SPA inside of an app folder?**

I'd like several static html files including an index.html at the root of the project.  I want these static HTML files served outside of the SPA for SEO purposes.

Right now, my project structure looks like this:

```
.
├── README.md
├── babel.config.js
├── package.json
├── public
│   ├── app
│   │   └── index.html
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   └── index.html
├── src
│   ├── App.vue
│   ├── assets
│   │   └── logo.png
│   ├── components
│   │   └── HelloWorld.vue
│   └── main.js
├── vue.config.js
└── yarn.lock
```

I've tried many different combinations of [publicPath](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath) and [indexPath](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#indexpath) values in my [vue.config.js](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js) file.  None have achieved what I'm hoping for.  I'd like *yarn serve* to serve both the static HTML files and SPA locally for development.  More importantly, I'd like the static HTML files and the SPA properly bundled into the dist folder when I run *yarn build*.  I haven't been able to achieve either goal.

With the configuration below, the public/index.html file that's meant to be static and only displaying at / is being served at both http://localhost:8080/ and http://localhost:8080/app/.  Interestingly, at http://localhost:8080/app/ the js resources are being injected into the response along with what's meant to be static HTML.

After running *yarn build* with the config below I'm left with a /dist/app/index.html file that has the static index.html file code with no javascript injected instead of the SPA code with javascript injected.  The /dist/index.html file has the static HTML I expect but all the javascript that's meant for the SPA is injected.

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
    publicPath: '/app/',
    indexPath: 'index.html'
}
```

**How can I configure this project to support static html files at the project root and an SPA in the app folder?**

Comment: I think for SEO purposes you have to use [NuxtJS](https://nuxtjs.org/) that will provide your component as HTML files.

Comment: @KushalSuthar I considered using NuxtJS but that seems like overkill for the few pages where I care about SEO.  The multipage apps option in the accepted answer works really well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage the feature of Vue CLI to [build multipage apps](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#building-a-multi-page-app) and actually have only one page...

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  pages: {
    index: {
      // entry for the page
      entry: "src/main.js",
      // the source template
      template: "public/app/index.html",
      // output as dist/app/index.html
      filename: "app/index.html",
      // when using title option,
      // template title tag needs to be <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
      title: "App Index Page",
      // chunks to include on this page, by default includes
      // extracted common chunks and vendor chunks.
      chunks: ["chunk-vendors", "chunk-common", "index"]
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I am not sure why this isn't a default thing for nested paths support